# Передвижение элемента с помощью DoubleAnimation wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, анимация

Здравствуйте. Есть функция, которая перемещает объект на одну клетку вправо. 
После анимации перемещения нужно сохранить текущее положение объекта. И при следующем вызове данной функции нужно выполнить анимацию перемещения уже из нового положения объекта.

Вот код функции

```
public void MoveRight(GameElement element)
 {
   TranslateTransform trans = new TranslateTransform();
   element.RenderTransform = trans;
   DoubleAnimation anim1 = new DoubleAnimation(0, Constants.CellSize, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
   trans.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.XProperty, anim1);
   element.PositionX += Constants.CellSize;
 }
```

Но, при следующем вызове данной функции, анимация все равно начинается с самой первой точки, не смотря на измененное положение объекта.

Пробовала таким образом:

```
DoubleAnimation anim1 = new DoubleAnimation(element.PositionX, element.PositionX + Constants.CellSize, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
```

Но тогда при первом вызове объект прыгает на расстояние `element.PositionX`, далее идет анимация.

Помогите, пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

Вариант "В лоб":
Подпишитесь на событие 
`anim1.Completed` и по факту его срабатывания устанавливайте актуальные значения положения для объекта.

Ещё на тему:
У анимации есть свойства/флаги  `anim1.IsAdditive` и  `anim1.IsCumulative`. Судя по описанию они управляют изменением параметров точек начала и конца анимации (я так понял координаты самого объекта не меняются). Попробуйте "поиграться" с данными флагами, возможно с их помощью реализуете необходимое вам поведение.

Comment: Может, лучше наоборот? «Увести» элемент в новое положение, установить анимацию из смещения старого положения относительно нового в ноль, и проиграть?

Comment: @VladD Как вариант. Я бы даже сказал более предпочтительный дабы не плодить лишнего кода. Такой подход позволит остаться в рамках MoveRight метода.